# Get Replied to comment from comment form

Tags: php, wordpress

While building a custom comment form, I need to get the ID of the comment that is being replied to ( if one is being replied to).

This is so the reply will be in the same market as the original comment.  For example, I need it to have the same value for that field as the original comment it is a reply for.

The market is a custom field, this would be a geographical area, but is really just a text field.  I also plan to make it read only, assuming I can get the information from the "parent" comment.

Some Wordpress plugin code ( simplified )

```
class clComments{

    public function init(){
        //display the custom fields in comment form
        add_filter('comment_form_fields', [$this,'clCustomCommentFields'] );
        //Save the custom fields
        add_action( 'comment_post', [$this,'clSaveCommentMetaData'] );
    }

    public function clCustomCommentFields($fields){
        /*-----------------------------------
          When replying to a comment I need to get that comment's
          id, so I can pull out the custom metadata for the comment
          that it is replying to
        -----------------------------------*/

        //$repledToId = ?; //this should be the id of the comment this is replying to

        $market = get_comment_meta( $repledToId, 'market', true );

        $fields['market'] = $this->clCustomCommentFieldMarket($market);
        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * I have bunch of custom fields so I don't like repeating myself
     */
    public function clCustomCommentNormalizeValue( $value ){
        if( false === $value){
            return '';
        }
        return 'value="'.esc_attr($value).'" ';
    }

    public function clCustomCommentFieldMarket($default = false){
         return '<p class="comment-form-market">'.
         '<label for="cf_market" style="display:block;" ><span class="required">*</span> '. __( 'What market(s) are you are interested in' ).'?</label>'.
         '<input id="cf_market" name="market" type="text" aria-required="true" required="required" '.$this->clCustomCommentNormalizeValue($default).'/></p>';
    }

    /**
     * save custom meta data
     */
    public function clSaveCommentMetaData($comment_id){
        if(!empty($_POST['market'])){
            add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'market', wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['market']) );
        }
    }

 }
```

Hopefully that makes sense, I just need the ID of the comment this comment is replying to.  But this has to be while building the comment form `filter:comment_form_fields`

If you need any more information feel free to ask. If your going to down vote it, at least show me the respect to tell me why.

**UPDATE**

Below is the screenshot of the comment form.  What I need is the comment at the bottom of the image, This has a value of "Any" for the "market" so I need to put this in the input when it "reply" mode.  Just to be clear, this is after clicking the "Reply" button on that comment.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply get this information for the $_GET array, such as

```
$_GET['replytocom'];
```

So in your class

```
public function clCustomCommentFields($fields){
    $market = get_comment_meta( $$_GET['replytocom'], 'market', true );

    $fields['market'] = $this->clCustomCommentFieldMarket($market);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the comment ID for the comment this form is replying to.   `I need to get the ID of the comment that is being replied`  You have a comment with a link that says "Reply To" when you click that and go to add a comment under that, I need that comments ID.  Not sure if you call that the "current" comment

Comment: So like first comment reply: ID1, second comment reply: ID2 etc...?

Comment: no, the comment that the reply button was specifically clicked on.  It the same one whos link appears in the comment form, but i was unable to find a worpress function for this.  So if I click reply on comment 4564, then I need comment 4564 when building the form so I can access its stored data.

Comment: ok, so for the third comment, if a user replies to that comment, the reply will have an id of 3?

Comment: It could, but that is unlikly.  It will have whatever ID the auto increment in the wp_post table was on when it was made.

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble understanding your question... Do you think you could reword it, or draw a diagram, so I could help you better?

Comment: No, I don't think I could "draw a diagram" It's pretty simple I need the comment that is being replied to.  So say you click the reply button for the first comment that has an id of `4564` when the page is loading the comment input form, I need that ID so I can get the information to put in the comment form.  I don't know how else to put it, it's not a matter of I need the third comment on the page, I need whatever comment this "new" one is in reply to.

Comment: Ah, I see... try using a POST method connected to the button or even GET to the reply button. I don't know how you have structured the reply button function, but look in to GET and POST methods and retrieving data from the users end. EDIT: you might also have to make it so the application tells the user what reply it is, so then you can retrieve it...

Comment: I didn't structure anything it's all built in wordpress functions, `get_comment_form` or such.  Wordpress builds it, if it was that simple I would not be here.

Comment: Actually that might work, I didn't think to check what was passed through the reply button.  I picked this site up after an outside developer bugged out on us ( my company ).  And besides my other duties, they left it in a pretty sorry state, so I been crammed trying to fix it up.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, but I updated your post so it's a proper answer.  Stupid mistake for me, easy points for you.  Cheers/  only the easy things stump me.